# material design toolbar on top of scrollbar

Tags: html, css, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

here is the the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bo7cYY9d0dfUe5wUYj6C?p=preview) example, I have a toolbar which is on top of my scrollbar, tried, but failed... Would be very appreciated if someone could help me.

Here is sample code:

`app.component.html`:

```
<md-toolbar class="fixed-header">
     <button class="app-icon-button" (click)="start.toggle()">
          <i class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu">menu</i>
     </button>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
      <md-sidenav #start class="app-sidebar" mode="side">
            test
      </md-sidenav>
      <div class="main-container-content" style="max-width:3px;">
            {{ text }}
      </div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: how to you want it to show up ?

Comment: Well now toolbar hides browser scrollbar...